# how to use datatable in php when we have large amunt of data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I used datatable jquery plugin it's working perfactly but now i have large amount of data like 100000 row so it just loading for 10-15 minutes can anyone suggent how to fix this loading issu with mysql and php using limit or something like this.

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: Not without seeing the php, database code and schema.

Comment: @jeff i cant share the backend data i just asking there is any possible way to limit the like i press next then it load other 10-50 record from database ?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i am using custom MVC getting data from database with sqli with simple query and place into jquery heml code. i need somthing to limit it and increase it on every next of datatable

Comment: @Mr_Rj You can use ajax with datatable. You can find sample code from it's website. It will load data on ajax call so all of your data not loaded at once. It will load data as per requested.

Below link may helpful for you.
https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/

Comment: thanks it works i got the concept post it as answer. @Yogendrasinh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you try a LIMIT clause in your query:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Your offset can be calculated by using the current page number - which could be passed in using jquery/ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Identify what is taking time and deal with it.  Focus on #9 and #11.

1. User does something ->
2. Action initiates JavaScript to do some action and instructs PC to send package to desired location ->
3. La la la->
4. Package gets to the targeted server and is directed to applicable service (which happens to be a web server such as Apache/nginx/etc) ->
5. Web server executes applicable PHP file and supplies applicable arguments ->
6. PHP manipulates request parameters and sends to MySQL ->
7. MySql executes query and returns results back to PHP ->
8. PHP manipulates results and sends back to user’s PC ->
9. La la la ->
10. User’s PC gets the results and gives them to JavaScript ->
11. JavaScript manipulates the results ->
12. User sees it